# Dynamic width on table columns in SSRS Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2010, report, ssrs-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Browsed quite a while for this on the web, trying different things with no luck.

As i understand, there's no support for putting an expression on the width of a table cell/column.

I saw there was a lot of complaining about this, and i could find no proper workaround for my scenario.

I'm creating a custom report designer where the customer can add fields and all they need in a ax form, I the create the report based on all this info.

I have a width property they can fill in the desired width of the field and need this to be reflected dynamically in Ax.

In Visual Studio 2010 i have this:
[image]
I have two tables, one for the headers and one for the data, in other words I can't "pad" the headers with empty spaces to make the columns expand it's width as a workaround, nor does it help to put expressions in the padding properties, as this does not expand the with of the column...

Any suggestions on this?

- I hope i don't have to modify the XML file for the report in AX, and would this even be possible considering deployment and everything?
- Is there anyway to set these properties in ax and make it happen automatically in the report?
- Is there any version of ssrs-reports that allows for width-expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this padding property? I can see this properties. I'm using SSRS 2008 R2

[image]

Comment: no, i can see the padding property too, but this does not affect the width of the columns. I'm looking for a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting all your headers in one field?

Why not put your headers in Column Grouping so they span across the page?
[image]